# ActiveRecord (Rails 3.0.1): API Can't Handle Too Many Requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, activerecord

I have an API that services a web-based plugin for processing email. The API is responsible for two things:

1. Creating SessionIDs so the plugin can setup a dynamic link; and
2. Once an email is sent, for receiving that SessionID, the email recipients and subject line, to store the information into a new session.

Imagine the scenario where the plugin sends a request to the API:

```
PUT http://server.com/api/email/update/<SessionID> -d "to=<address1,address2>&subject=<subject>"
```

In testing this works fine: the data is saved normally. However, the plugin can't help but send that request several times a second, bombarding my server with identical requests. The result is that I get my EmailSession object saving multiple copies of the recipients.

In terms of my database schema, I have an EmailSession model, which has_many EmailRecipients.

Here's the relevant part of the update method in my API's controller:

```
@email_session = EmailSession.find_or_create_by_session_id(:session_id => params[:id], :user_id => @user.id)

if opts[:params][:cm_to].blank? == false

    self.email_recipients.destroy_all                   

    unless opts[:params][:cm_to].blank?
        opts[:params][:cm_to].strip.split(",").each do |t|
            self.email_recipients << EmailRecipient.create(:recipient_email => t)
        end
    end
end
```

Admittedly, the "find_or_create" dynamic method is new to me, and I wonder if there's something about that screwing up the works.

The symptoms I'm seeing include:

- ActiveRecord errors complaining about attempts to save a non-unique key into the database (I have an index on the SessionId)
- Duplicate recipients ending up in the EmailRecipients collection
- In the case of multiple users employing the plugin, I get recipients from other emails ending up in the wrong email session collections.

I've attempted to employ delayed_job to attempt to serialize these requests somehow. I haven't had much luck with it thanks to various bugs in the current release. But I'm wondering if there's a more fundamental problem with my approach to this solution? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So  will multiple users be using the same session Id (but need separate EmailSession objects? What is supposed to happen if you get multiple requests naming the same recipient?

Comment: Yes, you'll have separate requests from different clients possibly adding the same recipients. And every email being written is a separate EmailSession object.

Comment: And different users (and by users i mean different values of @user.id)  are supposed to have different email session objects (with the same session_id) ?

Comment: Yes. Think about the purpose of this system: a user has this plugin that tracks all outgoing email. Every email they send has a new session. Every session has an arbitrary # of recipients. And there are many users. Hope this makes sense...

Comment: What is self in the above code (when you use self.email_recipients) . Is there a 3rd model here?

Comment: This method is actually in the EmailSession class; self refers to the passed-in EmailSession object. I've elided the statements in that code block above for the sake of brevity: the first line is from the controller, the remaining ones from the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure I understand what you're doing, but here's my advice.

First off I don't think you are using `find_or_create_by` properly. This method has slightly confusing semantics (which is why 3.2 introduces some clearer alternatives) but as it stands it isn't using the `user_id` to find the record (although it is setting `user_id` if a record is created). I don't think this is what you wanted. Instead use `find_or_create_by_session_id_and_user_id`

This can still raise a duplicate key error since in between `find_or_create` checking and it creating the record there is time for someone else to create the record. If you weren't doing anything other than creating email session rows the  rescuing this duplicate key error and then retrying should take of that: on the retry you'll find the row that blocked your insert.

However when you then go on to add recipients you still have a potential issue because 2 things could be trying to remove recipients and add them to the same email session at the same time. This might be a good usecase for pessimistic locking.

```
begin
  EmailSession.transaction do
    session = EmailSession.lock(true).find_or_create_by_bla_bla(...)
    # use the session object here, add recipients etc.
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
end
```

What is happening here is that when the email session is retrieved from the db, the row is locked (even if it doesn't exist yet - effectively you can lock the gap where the record would go). This means that anyone else wanting to add recipients or do any other manipulation has to wait for the lock to be released. Locks last as long as the transaction in which they occur lasts  so all your work should happen in here (even if in the second part you are not actually changing the email session object any more).

You may end up with deadlocks - I don't know what else is going on in your app but you should be prepared for them if you are using transactions. That's what the rescue block is for: if the error message looks like a deadlock then you should probably retry some limited number of times.

Locks are (at least on MySQL) row level locks: as long as you have an index on session_id,user_id then just because one of your instance has one email session object locked doesn't stop another instance from using another one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To the first point, I am using find_or_create as you suggest, and know that user_id will only be added on create; that's fine. But your points about the locking sound very promising. Let me try in the morning and I'll report back!